# C++ number-guessing game (computer tries to guess user's chosen number)

Tags: c++, beginner, number-guessing-game

In this program we input a number. Our PC tries to guess this number.

After every try PC asks us:"Are your number more or less than?".

We input 'l' if our number is less, and input 'h' if our number is greater?

A range of possible values ​​is created.

I think this code is bad.  What do you think?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int Random(int min, int max) {
    return min + rand() % (max - min);
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus"); 
    int our_num;
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    cout << "Input a positive number: " << endl;
    cin >> our_num;
    int t = 0;  //number of attempts
    int max = rand() + our_num;  //maximum possible value
    int min = 0;  //minimum possible value
    int d = Random(min, max);
    do {
        char lh;
        cout << d << " Is this your number?(my number is greater: 'h';   less: 'l')" << endl;
        cin >> lh;
        ++t;
        if (lh == 'h') {
            min = d;
            d = Random(min, max);
        }
        else if (lh == 'l') {
            max = d;
            d = Random(min, max);
        }
    } while (d != our_num);
    cout << "I guessed thus number with " << t << " attempts. " << "This number is " << d << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey Bogdasar, would you mind answering why specifically you believe this code is bad? Cheers!

Comment: @A.Romeu Have you never written something and had that terrible feeling that it's bad but couldn't quite say why?

Comment: Sure, a thousand times! But maybe there is some part you believe it can be definitely better for a reason, or something

Comment: One tip for improving the searching is to use binary search.

Comment: The `"rus"` locale would not be portable. You are probably better off setting the locale to `""` and having the user specify their preferred locale in the environment. However, in this example, you’re doing all the output in English anyway.

Comment: The most important thing I'd usually suggest is how to split the functionality of the program away from the UI and main() function, but this is actually a quite difficult example to do that to.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Some things stand out here:

- [Don't use `using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- [Consider not using `rand()`](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)
- [Prefer using `\n` over `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n)
- `return 0` can be dropped from main as it's optional
- You really need better variable names. Names should explain what the variable is used for. If you pick better names your superfluous comments can be removed alltogether

Comment: Elaborating on your final point, it's best not to use `min` and `max` potentially confusing since OP has brought `std::min/max` into the namespace.

Comment: I personally prefer to `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` from `main()`, albeit largely because that was the only correct way to do it when I was learning the language. I still prefer the consistency of not using the special-case rules for `main()`, and treating it like any other function that returns an `int`.

Comment: @Yuri you have basically invalidated how I learned to write C++ code

Answer (score 3):

Some considerations on user experience rather than programming style:

> ```
> cout << "Input a positive number: " << endl;
> cin >> our_num;
> ```

Why user should enter his number before the computer start guessing?? That's not a guessing game.

> int max = rand() + our_num;  //maximum possible value

should be the maximum number can be stored in an `int` (or give a range to the user ("choose a number between __ and __"))

> " Is this your number?(my number is greater: 'h';   less: 'l')"

I really miss the option when the guess is correct.

> ```
> int Random(int min, int max) {
>     return min + rand() % (max - min);
> }
> ```

I think it's really a good idea to put some variability in guessing instead of always going for boring binary search.